# How to control onselect before valuechanges

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I want to understand below issue which i am facing . I have a form with formgroup in it . I have a multiselect tag in the html which consists of (select) = onSelect(event)

Now in ts file i am using value changes to the template refernce of the multiselect tag ! And also onSelect method

My html

```
  <ds-multi-select>
  #costcenter
  [items] = “listofitems”
  [label] = “labelkey”
  [value] = “valuekey”
  (Select) = “onselect($event)”
  </ds-multi-select>
```

Inside a method in my ts file i have

```
this.form.get(“costCenter”).valuechanges.pipe().subsribe (costcheck 
 => {
  …..

    });
```

Also have separate function

```
   OnSelect(selectedItem:any)
  {
  IsSelected = SelectedItem.IsselectedItem
  }
```

Now whenever i hit the dropdown list, the valuechanges is getting called first and then onSelect method. I want to use Isselected value from onSeelect function inside valuechanges. I want onSelect to be called first and use the valuechanges later.

I also tried to check in the valuechanges event if I could catch the checkbox is selected or not attribute but couldn't find anything !

Please help with the correct solution !

Comment: You should not listen to the select event, only the form control's change event

Comment: Couldnt get you . can you give an example?

Comment: valuechanges emits the selected value, so you can definitely see what is checked.

Comment: @salketer I can see what is checked but i couldn't see what the status? is it checked or unchecked ? like in both cases i would see the value when it is checked and unchecked but not the status true or false while selecting and unseelcting

Comment: Since you did not show your code for this part, we cannot help much more.

Comment: I don't know why your fixating on whenever which function calls first. Can't you just put your desired functionality inside the function that fires first?

Comment: @adithyasurya34 I'm not sure which part you didn't understand. If you are using reactive forms, you should use `this.form.get(“costCenter”).valuechanges.subscribe` and not use `(Select) = “onselect($event)”` since the form's `valuechanges` is an abstraction over the raw HTML events and you can listen to every form object the same way. As others have mentioned, why are you listening to both?

Comment: @JuanMendes because while listening valuechange i want to fetch the status of checkbox like its selected or not ? If a item in list ischecked then true nor false. So if i try to use onSelect event i am able fetch that status from that event but couldn’t find same in valuechanges from the form